# 'Chroot' mounted wim file (windows)

Tags: windows-10, sdk, waik

Is there a way to open a sort of chroot like shell window that limits itself to a mounted Windows 10 installation? (mounted with dism from install.wim) I thought since it's possible to load the registry hives from the mounted installation. Would it also be possible to open a shell environment for the mounted environment, in order to be able to execute commands that affect the mounted environment.

I have done this before in Linux with chroot to prepare a custom distro.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is sysprep.

Comment: Could you explain how to use it on a mounted installation? I found it can read answer files so I guess I can put my shell command in there.

Comment: You cannot. Of course, if your customizations are just programs capable of unattended installation, the answer file may be suitable.